# Где можно взять реализацию sharedptr и weakedptr?

Tags: указатели, c++

Доброго времени суток! Классы `sharedptr` и weakedptr` еще не были включены в стандарт С++11, но насколько мне известно, были включены в TR1. Где можно найти код их реализации?

Comment: Отчего же, включены. Только они называются [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) и [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).

Comment: @VladD да, я ошибся, но, все равно, где можно найти реализацию методов этих классов?

Comment: @aapetrov3: например, возьмите из какого-нибудь компилятора, который их поддерживает. Например, свежего gcc. Учтите, что эта реализация может опираться на новые фичи C++11 и оказаться не переносимой на компилятор, который C++11 не поддерживает.

Comment: @aapetrov3: да, а для старого компилятора лучше воспользоваться [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) и [boost::weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm).

Comment: @VladD я в своем компиляторе не нашел, можете подсказать ссылку на правильный?

Comment: @aapetrov3: `boost` нужно загрузить с boost.org, он не поставляется с компиляторами. Очень советую посмотреть на их библиотеки, очень много полезного, a must для C++-разработки. Большинство библиотек header-only, то есть не требуют специальных .dll/.so.

Comment: @aapetrov3, пожалуйста
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01519_source.html
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01518_source.html

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

1. Умные указатели включены в стандарт c++11 (`std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`)
2. Находятся они в хедере`<memory>` (т.е. для подключения необходимо написать следующее: `#include <memory>`), в стандартном stl-ом пространстве имен `std`
3. Насколько мне известно мелкомягкие склоняются к политике закрытого кода, т.е. все, что вы видите в microsoft'их хедерах либо обфусцировано, либо вообще неактуально (живой тому пример - это функция `strlen`, её настоящая реализация сильно отличается о той, которую вы при желании можете найти в их исходных файлах у себя на диске (в директории visual studio, например). 
   Например, для 13 студии можно найти здесь: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\strlen.c", а ведь по факту она считывает по 4 байта за раз и выполняет побитовые операции для нахождения символа конца строки, но, опять же, её настоящая реализация может разниться от одной версии студии к другой)
4. Так как данные умные указатели попали в 11 стандарт непосредственно из boost, то сколько-нибудь актуальную их реализацию можно найти, например, на [их сайте](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

---

Таким образом, ссылки на boost-овскую реализацию: [shared_ptr](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp), [weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.hpp).

Comment: По факту размотка цикла в `strlen` является стандартной оптимизацией и производится на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @VladD На самом деле я говорил совсем не о размотке цикла, а о том, что реальная реализация, например, `strlen` совсем не такая банальная как можно подумать. Например, у них там должно быть что-то вот [в таком духе](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1E1-m-HTT5qbUh3MnNQQlBmTW8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Ну у вас в коде и есть (по крайней мере частично) ручная размотка цикла, в блоки по 4 штуки. Это же оптимизирующий компилятор делает сам, без помощи программиста. (Я не вполне понял специальное обращение с не-ASCII-символами.)

Comment: @VladD Я так понимаю, что 'в результате применения раскрутки цикла должно увеличиваться количество инструкций, которые потенциально могут выполняться параллельно', но у меня там никакой параллельностью и не пахнет (в цикле за рез все также выполняется одна операция), просто там весь алгоритм сместился в сторону бинарной составляющей (т.е. прям совсем другой алгоритм стал). Чтобы за одну бинарную операцию (ну, по факту 2) можно было наверняка узнать есть ли в 1ом из 4 байт 0 или нет, т.е. там ведь не предполагается выполнение 4 параллельных сравнений каждое по одному байту. Ну либо я ошибаюсь:)

Comment: Почему же? Раскрутка цикла — это как раз выполнение по нескольку итераций цикла за раз. 4 итерации = 4 сравнения чисел, автовекторизатор сворачивает это в сравнение одно 4-байтного числа. Никакой особой магии, по идее. (А параллельность есть, у вас за одну итерацию сравниваются «параллельно» 4 значения.)

Comment: @VladD Окей, спасибо. Честно говоря, никогда раньше не слышал об `автоматической векторизации`, но приму к сведению :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35264/discussion-between-stateitprimitive-and-vladd).

Comment: Это я так коряво перевёл [automatic vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization).

Comment: Хотя, я вот проверил, свежий gcc вроде не векторизирует. Надо бы спросить у наших гуру С++. Возможно, эта оптимизация в свежих версиях не применяется? Хм.